# Installing new HDDs in RAID1 on existing Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS system

Tags: 14.04, server, hard-drive, raid

I have a system running Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS. It is configured and working just fine.

I'm planning to add two HDDs and set up RAID1 for redundancy and resiliency.

The question is: should I

1. clone existing system partitions to a new drive
2. connect second new HDD
3. set up mdadm and other things there
4. transfer data from old HDD (few terabytes, huge amount of files)
   or I should I do #4 after #1 straight away?

Looking for a detailed guide on how to set up mdadm and related things (it has been already suggested in comments to go with Linux software RAID instead of built-in into motherboard).

Comment: First of all, ignore what your motherboard supports. You do **not** have HW RAID. You have [fake raid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto). Stick with dm, which is native raid functionality in Linux. Second - I suggest to actually reinstall, as you have a rather old version of Ubuntu, that is EOL quite a while ago. Moving a system to new partitions is doable, but involves booting from a live cd, and reinstalling the boot loader and modifying *at least* `/etc/fstab`. So in short: reinstall, and use software raid.

Comment: @vidarlo Ok, I suspected that. Does this mean I should NOT turn RAID in BIOS at all? As for reinstall - the machine is a home server with bunch of services set up over the course of recent 4 years, I don't think I will be able to replicate that from scratch. I'm not sure if I will be even able to upgrade it to something newer. Looking for some magic migration tool ><.

Comment: Indeed - do not turn on raid in the BIOS. There is no magic migration tool that I'm aware of - and migrating is likely to be at least as complex as setting up the services anew, and with a fair chance of data loss. In addition it's not advised to run old software...

Comment: What happened? Did you suddenly end up with Ubuntu 14.04 on a system that you claimed is difficult to upgrade?

Comment: @DavidFoerster it took an evening and few brain cells, but it looks like bump was successful. Few applications turned out to be incompatible with new version, few were not updated, but I even forgot they existed, so I'm good. Now looking for detailed guide on how to set up software raid as previously suggested.

Comment: Alright. I'll take your word and vote to reopen your question. **To reopen voters:** OP upgraded to a supported Ubuntu release. Please see our short conversation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I went with second scenario and made it as safe as possible:

1. I've installed first new HDD and cloned system partitions AND all data to it using Acronis Disk Director. That was the easiest and quickest part.
2. Booted from it and set up mdadm, changed partition types to Linux raid (fd).
3. Connected second new drive, copied partitions layout with sgdisk, rsynced all data from first drive. It literally took ages (like few days per partition on my Atom-powered box). I did this because no guide indicated it is possible to clone everything directly and I decided not to risk.
4. Changed partition types on HDD #2 to Linux raid, re-assembled GRUB.

The whole project took few weeks in general, but the system eventually was set up and working as expected. I wiped my old drives only then, and strongly advise you to do the same.
 There were a lot of problems along the way of configuration, but here are blog posts and articles that helped me the most:

- [Configuring Software RAID1 after installation of Ubuntu 16](https://www.considerednormal.com/2016/10/configuring-software-raid1-after-installation-of-ubuntu-16/)
- [Setting up RAID on an existing Debian/Ubuntu installation](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/setting-up-raid-on-existing/)
- [How To Set Up Software RAID1 On A Running System (Incl. GRUB2 Configuration) (Ubuntu 10.04)](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-ubuntu-10.04)